# TableLayoutPanel auto size problem with large space between rows

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel, autosize

I am having an issue with using tablelayoutpanel to layout controls. The structure of the layout is as follow: the parent layout has several rows and each row contains a layout with 3 columns. I set autosize to all the layout and controls. The layout works as expected for most cases but sometimes I get the extremely large space between rows. And this space is different when I maximize the window.
Please see the screen captures below:

**This is the normal window size**
[image: This is the normal window size]

**This is the maximized window**
[image: This is the maximized window]

Both spaces in these images are not correct. These rows are supposed to be close to each other.

Please help me explain why this happens. Thank you very much!

Comment: You didn't specify whether the TLP is anchored/docked in some way. If it's docked, try changing it to anchored to {Left, Top, Right}. Since it could expand on the Y dimension, put it inside a scrollable control (a `Panel` or a `FlowLayoutPanel`).

Comment: I do not like the tablelayoutpanel due to issue like this.  I create my own by using one Main Panel and then adding my own array of panels to the main panel.  Same affect with much more properties and control of the properties.

Comment: I use TLPs all the time and they take some getting used to. Make sure the controls inside the TLP are anchored at least to left, top and bottom. Then in the TLP rows wizard, make sure they are all set to autosize.

Answer (score 0):

My table for some reason ended up with 2 row styles and 2 column styles. Maybe it's defaulted this way because it assumes a header row / column. Anyway, this worked for me:

```
table.RowStyles.Clear();
table.ColumnStyles.Clear();
```